# Cannot find module 'express' in node

Tags: node.js

Cannot find module 'express' in server side. [image: error]

Comment: Basic questions.  Did you install the Express module in the project directory with `npm install express`?  Please show us the part of your `index.js` file that the Express module and triggers the error.  If you go into your project directory (where `index.js` is located) and type `npm info express`, what does it show?  Please add this information to your question using the "edit" link below your question.

Answer (score 1):

Always note to use `npm i` when ever you clone into the server to install missing packages.

Answer (score 0):

the express package is not found in local node_modules packages

try add it with

```
npm i express
```